# How to specify the order of running spec files with jest ? E.g: run first spec.fille1.js then spec.file2.js etc

Tags: express, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I want to run my spec files in this order:

```
spec.file2.js,

spec.file3.js,

spec.file5.js,

spec.file1.js
```

I want to configure it with jest. Need help...

Comment: Is that what you truly desire though? The idea of these unit tests is that they are independent of each other and can be run in any order.  Tests that start to depend on each other, will become harder to maintain over time, and add extra dependencies that will make refactoring code harder as well.

Answer (score 0):

As specified in this link,  https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6194

Have an index file, call it index.spec.js, that dictates the order in which you'd execute:

```
require('./spec.file2.js')
require('./spec.file3.js')
require('./spec.file5.js')
require('./spec.file1.js')
```

Just make sure that there are no other related tests that match against the jest default testMatch unless other-wise custom defined